# Smalltalk How to create immutable instance variable?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks, gnu-smalltalk

I have a class with an instance variable var.
I don't want the variable to be modified / assigned to a value except when the object is created using a Class method.

isImmutable: aBoolean is the method to convert a mutable object to an immutable object and vice-versa.
Can someone please provide me the correct syntax to do it?

Comment: I implemented it by modifying the accessor method like this:
var1: anObject
 var1 := anObject.
 self isImmutable: true.
Is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented it using the code:

```
MyClass class>>classMethod: aValue

anObject := self new value:aValue.
anObject isImmutable: true.
^anObject.
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I'm pretty certain that isImmutable won't do the trick.  Assuming that does actually make an object immutable, it will make the object *pointed to* by the instVar immutable, not the instvar itself.

Your best bet is to simply not include a specific Mutator for the variable at all, but to instead set it at initialization time like this:

```
MyClass class>>newWithFoo: aFoo
   ^self basicNew initializeWithFoo: aFoo; yourself

MyClass>>initializeWithFoo: aFoo
   self initialize.
   foo := aFoo.
```

That way, the only way anyone outside the class itself can affect the variable is by creating a new instance by calling `MyClass newWithFoo:`

(Not counting using reflective methods like `#instVarNamed:put:` - there's pretty much nothing you can do about them, but anyone using them knows they're breaking the contract of the class anyway).

Comment: Stuart Herring I heard that modifying/implementing basicNew is not a good object oriented design practice.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you modify or implement basicNew - only that you call it.
What I suggested was one of two common was of creating a class side instance creation method - you usually either call `#new`, and then public setters for the values you want to set, or you call `#basicNew` and explicitly call an initialization method that will set the initial values (which allows you to not have a public setter for those variables, effectively giving you immutability).

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to make the object immutable? Isn't it enough to declare your API in a way that makes it obvious how to use the class and to not replace the instance variable?

Comment: I was trying to learn how to use the isImmutable in smalltalk.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that immutability operates at a single level in the object graph. Instance variables are a bit like a constant pointer in C++, the address cannot change, but the contents can change.
Here is a little example:

```
| a b |
a := Array with: 1.
b := Array with: a.
b beImmutable.
b at: 1 put: nil.
^b
```

Will end up with a NoModificationError, you cannot write any instance/indexed variable of b since b is immutable.
But you can write into the objects pointed by the instance/indexed variables of b:

```
| a b |
a := Array with: 1.
b := Array with: a.
b beImmutable.
a at: 1 put: 2.
^b
```

Will succeed, and b is now #(#(2)) instead of #(#(1))

You can also arrange to propagate the immutability further down the object graph if ever that's what you are after (but beware of cycles).